# Почему при вводе отрицательных значений элементов списка, компилятор выдает ошибку? IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
a = [int(g) for g in input().split()]
b = 0
for i in a:
   print(a[i-1])
   b += a[i-1]
print(b)
```

Ошибка:     print(a[i-1]) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Допустим, нулевой элемент равен 20, длина списка а равна 5. Что должно выйти при обращении к a[19]?

Comment: попробуйте заменить `for i in a:` на  `for i in range(len(a)):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим вы ввели: `5 6 8`
Тогда на первой итерации цикла в выражении `i-1` содержится число `4`. А элемента с таким номером в списке `a` не существует.
Предлагаю такое исправление вашего кода:

```
a = [int(g) for g in input().split()]
b = 0
for i in a:
   print(i)
   b += i
print(b)
```

Либо такой вариант

```
a = [int(g) for g in input().split()]
b = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
   print(a[i])
   b += a[i]
print(b)
```